# Is SSRS server accepts credential from machine or WinForm application?

Tags: windows, winforms, reporting-services

I just want to confirm something. Let's say if i have a WinForm application to view SSRS report. My machine is set as UserA. In that WinForm application i use credential as UserB to view a report in WebBrowser Control. Will the SSRS Portal process my request using credential from my machine or my WinForm application? Thank you.

Comment: It will use the credentials provided in the WinForm, assuming they are not set to 'Windows Authentication".

Comment: Remove UserB from the SSRS Portal and see what happens? What is your connection string in the app?